# Show a notification message with "Run script" mode for Action (Retool)

Tags: javascript, notifications, event-handling, run-script, retool

With **"Show notification" mode** for **Action** and other settings as shown below, I could show **a notification message** on the top right corner of the screen:

[image]

This is **the notification message** on the top right corner of the screen:

[image]

Now, with **"Run script" mode** for **Action** as shown below, I want **the same notification message** as shown above:

[image]

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"utils.showNotification()"** function with **one object which contains 4 values "title"**, **"description"**, **"notificationType"** and **"duration"**.

```js
utils.showNotification({ 
  title: "something", 
  description: "something", 
  notificationType: "info", // "info", "success", "warning" or "error" is available
  duration: 5 // If "duration" isn't set, 4.5 is set. 
});
```

This is the code to show **the same notification message** with **"Run script" mode** for **Action**:

```js
utils.showNotification({ 
  title: "This is title.", 
  description: "This is description", 
  notificationType: "info", 
  duration: 5 
});
```

[image]

Then, you can show **the same notification message** with **"Run script" mode** for **Action**:

[image]